# LMA and private listing questions

Tags: salesforce

Can I get LMA for my app without going through the security review process?

I submitted a case for requesting the LMA, salesforce rep. replied that in order to get LMA, my app need to go through security review,
but according to ISVforce Guide, it seem that I can have LMA for my private listed app.  I am confuse, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the LMA app, you need to at least show an intent to put your app through a security review, and you generally to sign a term sheet with Salesforce.com regarding your app, even if you don't intend to list your app publicly.  I'm not sure what the policy is if you're offering only a free app (you don't mention whether your app is free or paid), but if it is free, you have nothing to lose by going through the security review, as free apps get free security reviews.

In any case a security review for a paid app is only $300, which is usually not a huge barrier, and is probably worth it for the benefits the LMA provides.  Plus your app will be more secure because of it.